# jquery-confirm change translation property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-confirm

I'm using jquery-confirm 3.2.0 for confirmation box. Confirm box is appearing at center of the screen. How to make it to appear at the top of the screen?

Comment: Welcome to SO https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: It's hard to offer advice without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try you following code, I found they using following CSS to make it center it:

```
.jconfirm .jconfirm-cell {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Also have `option` `alignMiddle : false` but 'alignMiddle' method deprecated in new version.

Comment: Thank you. <alignMiddle : false> worked for 3.2.3 version.